# how to close php resource in generator functions

Tags: javascript, php

When I use iterators how to close the resources after that.

For example - if I have generator method like this:

```
$fileHandler = fopen($filePath, 'r');

while ($line = fgetcsv($fileHandler)) {
    yield $line;
}

fclose($fileHandler);
```

How to make sure the 'fclose' will be called.

If i call the generator and i only get the first 3 rows from the csv the while loop will be paused and if dont call the next values 'fclose' will not be called.

How to make sure that the file handler will be closed.

Comment: Do you have to check for a done status?

Comment: For example sometimes I will need 3 rows. But the csv could contain more. I wonder if it's possible to close the iterator whenever I dont need the generator anymore. Otherwise if i get only 3 rows the resource can cause memory leaks.

Comment: Use try-finally: https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.generators.overview.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put it in a `try`, `catch`, `finally` block. Finally will always get executed.

```
$fileHandler = fopen($filePath, 'r');
try {    
    while ($line = fgetcsv($fileHandler)) {
        yield $line;
    }
} catch(Exception $e) {
   //Do something with error.
} finally {
   fclose($fileHandler); 
}
```

Comment: Thanks, i found similar solution in php docs. But I wonder: If the function is paused (for example when i get the 3 rows) how the generator understand that is done and call finally ? If the generator is paused how it will proceed to 'finally'. Maybe when the garbage collector destroy the generator variable?

Answer (score -1):

Best way is to handle the resource like this

```
if(is_resource($fileHandler)) fclose($fileHandler);
```

Comment: This does not address the actual question.